# changing a global variable inside a loop

Tags: python, loops, variables

```
import turtle    

t = turtle.Turtle()

times = int(input("How many points would you like to draw?"))


for side in range (times):

    move = input("which way would you like too go?\n\n1: Forward\n2: Backward\n3: Right\n4: Left\n5: Change Color\n6: Exit")

    if (move == str(1)):
        t.forward(50)

    if (move == str(2)):
        t.backward(50)

    if (move == str(3)):
        t.right(90)

    if (move == str(4)):
        t.left(90)

    if(move == str(5)):
        color = input("What color would you like?")
        t.color(color)

    if (move == str(6)):
        break

    else:
        break
```

(This may be a dumb question I'm pretty new to python)
I want to make the turtle move using user input, and making it move works fine, but I want to change the color of the turtle and have the color remain constant inside the loop. I'm not sure how to do this or what to research for this so I'm asking on here.

Thank You

Comment: Use `t.color()` to change the turtle color.

Comment: You've already written code to change the color.  How does this not work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune it changes color but it breaks the loop

Comment: why do you have a break?  What is your for loop doing if you defeat it with a break?  else: break...will end the loop regardless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else:
    break
```

This `else` will execute whenever the `if` immediately preceding it is False:

```
if (move == str(6)):
    break
```

So as long as `move` is anything other than `6`, your loop will end.

If you only want to break when `move` isn't 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6, change all of your `if`s except the first one to `elif`s.

```
if (move == str(1)):
    t.forward(50)

elif (move == str(2)):
    t.backward(50)

elif (move == str(3)):
    t.right(90)

elif (move == str(4)):
    t.left(90)

elif(move == str(5)):
    color = input("What color would you like?")
    t.color(color)

elif (move == str(6)):
    break

else:
    break
```

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that first casting `move` to an integer, instead of continuously casting each integer to a string in each comparison would be cleaner. Or use literal strings instead such as `'1'` instead of `str(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Change all your `if` statements except the first to `elif`. The problem is that the `else:` at the end is only attached to `if (move == str(6)):`, so any move other than `6` causes you to break out of the loop.

```
if (move == '1'):
    t.forward(50)

elif (move == '2'):
    t.backward(50)

elif (move == '3'):
    t.right(90)

elif (move == '4'):
    t.left(90)

elif(move == '5'):
    color = input("What color would you like?")
    t.color(color)

elif (move == '6'):
    break

else:
    break
```

Also, just write `'1'` instead of `str(1)`. Or convert the input to `int` and then use just `if move == 1:`